# Android Emulator Devices not shown in Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator, xamarin.forms

I use Visual Studio 2015 and I'm confused about the Android Emulators in my Xamarin Forms Project. Android Studio and Visual Studio (-> Tools -> Android -> Android Emulator Manager) show 4 Emulators, but in the dropdown list I don't see them but 4 others. These others are available in Visual Studio -> Tools -> Visual Studio Emulator for Android..... ?

Screenshots are available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3xSO.jpg).

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good afternoon!
Each program has its own emulators. Visual Studio recognizes machines(android devices) created on visual studio emulator. To make those available in AVD  (Android virtual device manager) appear in VS dropdown, try to start them in AVD first, then run your application in it

Comment: I've edited the AVD in VS Tools -> Android -> Android Emulator Manager so that the Question Marks are gone. When I tried to start I got error that I have to disable Hyper-V, see [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/k1uf0xM.png) . After doing so and restarting the machine, the AVD is shown in the dropdown! I could select it and start debugging! Many thanks!!